# URL with Object values in PHP toString method

Tags: php, object, url

New to PHP, doing academical exercise. I have a website that lets you add cars from add-car.php. Car is an object with make, model, grade from Post.php. Add-car.php creates an entry and displays it on index.php with make, model and year.

I need to make the car entry 'make' into a hyperlink that lets me edit the original entry by taking me back to add-car.php with the values (make, model, year) already inserted into the form.

I have already implemented  etc. into the original form, so that if there is an error (eg. model text is too long or too short) it keeps the previous value.

What I have trouble with is creating the correct hyperlink with values when the car entry is created. Right now I have in Post.php:

```
public function __toString(): string {

$url = printf('<a href=car-add.php?id=' . $this->id);

return printf('<div>"$url"</div><div>%s</div><div></div><div>%s</div>', $this->make, $this->model);
```

Output is:

```
<a href=book-add.php?id=12<div>26</div><div>BMW</div><div></div><div>5</div>54
<a href=book-add.php?id=13<div>26</div><div>Mercedes</div><div></div><div>5</div>54
```

No idea where the nr 26 and 54 are coming from.
Output should look like this:

```
<div><a href=book-add.php?id=12></a></div><div>BMW</div><div></div><div>I5</div>

<div><a href=book-add.php?id=13</a></div><div>Mercedes</div><div></div><div>Vito</div>54
```

I'm expecting that the hyperlink from index.php takes me back to add-car.php with the values of the Car object already inserted into the text fields.

Edit: Each car also gets an ID when a post is created, but I'm unsure how to implement the id.  Car ID is in a separate txt.

Comment: _"Each car also gets an ID when a post is created"_ - then _that_ is what you should be passing. And in your target script, you _find_ the specific car in whatever your actual storage solution is, based on that ID.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the code that retrieves the information from the URL and uses it to populate the form. The first thing I'd think of if it's inserting the string `$make` is that you're using single-quotes instead of double-quotes.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the make as a text string within the car table - that should be a separate table with its own unique ID, and that ID should be stored in your table.

Comment: Any materials online on how to do that? All I've found is people creating 'edit' buttons with code like <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>", which in essence is the same thing, but how do I put all that into the printf. I get stuck in this kind of '"'"'" hell. @CBroe

Comment: Using `<?php ... ?>` _again_, when you are already _in_ such a block, does not work. _'I get stuck in this kind of '"'"'" hell'_ - maybe you should not use sprintf there to begin with, but rather this syntax: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this? What does the code currently do? What should it do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *sprintf()* to get the url into `$url`. If you use *printf()*, `$url` will always be a number, because [printf()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.printf.php) returns the string length created. That's why you see the extra numbers.

```
$url = sprintf('<a href=car-add.php?id=' . $this->id);
```

Same is valid for your *return* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Markus Zeller. Got it formatted and working. Way better answer than my teacher gave. He basically said that I made too many mistakes to answer online.

```
$url = '<a href=car-add.php?title=' . $this->title . '>';

return sprintf('<div>' . $url . '%s</a></div><div></div><div>%s</div>', $this->title, $this->grade);
```

Comment: I am happy I could help you. Please delete this answer, because SO works that way, other people answer questions and the best fitting one is marked as "correct answer" by the one who asked. :D Have a nice day, my programmer friend.